# C++ find repeating symbols in vector

Tags: c++, histogram, std

How do I exactly find how many repeating symbols do I have in a `std::vector`?

The idea is to write the following program - You enter a sequence of symbols (should be letters), like:

```
aaaabbbccccc
```

Which is, of course, a string, which is then written into a `vector` (well I guess that if you write it into a `vector`, it will be much easier for iterations)

And the output is: `4a3b5c` (as to there are four `a`'s, three `b`'s and five `c`'s)

My main problem is finding the repeating symbols and doing operations with them.

Comment: This is called [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) - a simple compression algorithm. Google this and you will find many articles about this including examples in C++. It seems to be a common assingment nowadays.

Comment: Didn't know about that, thank you very much. Oh yes, it is indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way to achieve the same thing. This is probably a little more efficient than the `std::map` based solution due to `std::array` being contiguous in memory and supports arbitrary input and output containers via iterators.

It is possible to use an array because we can have only 256 distinct characters.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>

template <
    typename InputIter,
    typename OutputIter,
    typename = typename std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<
            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type,
            char>>>
OutputIter encode(InputIter begin, InputIter end, OutputIter out)
{
    constexpr auto num_chars = std::numeric_limits<char>::max();
    std::array<int, num_chars> counts = {};
    while (begin != end)
        ++counts[*begin++];
    for (char i = 0; i < num_chars; ++i)
        if (counts[i] > 0)
            *out++ = std::make_pair(i, counts[i]);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v = {
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'};
    std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> out;
    encode(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
    for (auto e : out)
        std::cout << e.second << e.first;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Nice generic, STL-like solution. But, why has it to be limited to `char`? Why not use `std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type` instead of simply `char` and therefore replace `std::array` with `std::vector` in order not to blow the stack? That way, it would be even more generic.

Comment: I'm not sure how a vector would help. If the input was just one really large number, this function would do a lot of unnecessary work. If I were to make this more generic, I would use a map/unordered_map rather than a vector or an array.

Comment: What about defining different template specializations that use different data structures (i.e.; `std::vector` or `std::unordered_map`) and then select the right specialization by means of SFINAE?

Comment: Yes, that would work if I needed this for a real project. I guess this function should suffice as far as this question goes ;)

Comment: Sure, I agree. We leave that topic as a simple suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `std::map` for keeping the count of the symbols as you iterate  the `std::vector`, and use the elements of the `std::vector` as the keys for the `std::map`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> vec{'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
                          'b', 'b', 'b',
                          'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'};

    std::map<char, int> cnt;

    // count symbols
    for (auto elem: vec)
        cnt[elem]++;

    // display count
    for (auto elem: cnt)
        std::cout << elem.second << elem.first;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Running the code above will produce the output `4a3b5c`.

Comment: The problem with using a `std::map` is that the resulting string may come out in a different order than the original string.  For example, `ccccaabbb` would produce `2a3b4c`, not `4c2a3b`.

Comment: Thank you very much, will surely checkout the code above.
What is your opinion on PaulMcKenzie's comment about map being problematic with the order?

Comment: You are right. How the resulting string will come out depends on how the keys are internally sorted in the `std::map`. The count, however, will be right.

Comment: Oh okay, then it won't be a problem i guess. Well if it is problematic at the end, i will try to write a sorting algorithm to sort it out. Thank you very much for the help